# Selecting features whose text is equal to the text after certain word in QGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, field-calculator, select-by-expression

I have origin-destination lines and I'm looking for intra-city lines or lines whose origin and destination are in the same city.

A sample intra-city feature would be `"Quezon_City to Quezon_City"` and inter-city would be `"Quezon_City to CALOOCAN_CITY"`.

I'd like some help in writing an expression that selects all features whose string before `"to"` is the same with the string after it using Python or Expression Builder.

Comment: Yes. The pattern is 'origin' to 'destination' for all features.

Comment: It works! Thank you!!! Saved me a lot of time (and errors)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently I have two ideas how to tackle your issue

**Case 1.** Only working with an Attribute table where you will need to use the following expression

```py
if(left("test",regexp_match("test",'\\ to ')-1) = right("test",regexp_match("test",'\\ to ')-1), true, false)
```

**Case 2.** Working with geometries of lines and polygons, of course if you have cities as polygons.

So, geometrically check if starting and ending points of the "origin-destination"-lines are both within those polygons. In PostGIS-interpretation it might be something like

```sql
st_within(start_point(line.geometry), polys.geometry)
AND st_within(end_point(line.geometry), polys.geometry)
```

Answer (score 4):

@Taras has already given an answer that solves your problem.
Let me give you another one using **PyQGIS**.

I have an attribute table with 2 fields: `descriptions` which corresponds to your text and `equal` to indicate whether the text before `to` is identical to the text after `to`.

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer() # your layer
layer.startEditing()

# Loop on each feature of the layer
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    feat_text = feat["description"] # your text
    pos_to = feat_text.find("to") # find the position of the word "to"
    before_to = feat_text[:pos_to].replace(" ", "") # Extract the text before the previous position and remove blank lines
    after_to = feat_text[pos_to+2:].replace(" ", "") # Extract the text after 
    
    # Update of the "equal" field depending the text before and after
    if before_to == after_to:
        feat["equal"] = 'yes'
        layer.updateFeature(feat)
    else:
        feat["equal"] = 'no'
        layer.updateFeature(feat)
    
layer.commitChanges()
```